# Test for C++11 in GCC 4.6

Tags: c++11, gcc

This fails to compile under GCC 4.6:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <ratio>
#endif
```

__cplusplus should be set to "1" in GCC 4.6 according to this bug:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773

How should I test for C++11 support in GCC 4.6?

EDIT: I want to use Boost ratio when built with GCC 4.6 and std ratio with GCC 4.8 and -std=c++11. The rest of the code is ready for this, it's just this include that fails to compile.

Comment: It's better to test for known-to-work compilers and versions. So you can use `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__`.

Comment: `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` maybe? But at this point, I would just consider that gcc-4.6 (and older) did not support C++11, much simpler and does not exclude that many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since even compilers which theoretically support this or that standard version can have bugs, it's better to rely on specific versions which are known to produce valid results.

In G++, you can do:

```
#if __GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 9
  // use C++11 features
#else if __GNUC__ == 5
  // use C++11 features
#else
  // maybe don't use some features
#endif
```

Comment: Would it not be better for the long-term to use `#else if __GNUC__ > 4` (or `>= 5`)?  There'll be a GCC 6.x someday, and it would be irksome to have code break because of carelessness.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes; my main concern was to show how to take into consideration the various versions, and specifically not to do something like (major >= 4 && minor >= 9) -- i.e. what if major == 5 and minor == 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to compile this program:

```
int main()
{
  auto i = 0;
  return 1;
}
```

using the command `g++ -std=c++11 -c filename.cpp` in your command line. `auto` is c++11 feature, so if that compiles with no errors, it means your compiler has support for C++11.

But in general, for gcc, before version 5.1, support for C++11 was experimental. So not until version 5.1 that gcc supported everything C++11 has to offer.

Comment: "it means your compiler supports C++11" -- It means your compiler supports that one particular feature of C++11. It says nothing about any other features of C++11. If you're going to try compiling test programs to see if the compiler accepts a certain feature, it's better to test for exactly the feature you want. In this case, the test program could be `#include <ratio>` / `int main() {}`.

Comment: @hvd You're right, the structure of my sentence was misleading. Modified it.